# Why are routed events fired after initializing the user control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I am working on a WPF application and I have a window with a grid in it and a few user controls. The problem arises when I add these user controls to the grid from the code behind (through C#),

```
// UserControlA is the user control with all the working content
var ucA = new UserControlA;       
Grid.Children.Add(ucA);
```

There are two things that happen here, one is the user control is initialized, the second is any load events I have in the code behind of the user control also get fired.

The reason I have these load events like is because before the user control is presented to any employee then it should check for employee authorization, so instead of doing this

```
public partial class UserControlA : UserControl
{
    public UserControlA()
    {
        IntializeComponent();
        Authorize(); 
    }
}
```

I do this:

```
public partial class UserControlA : UserControl
{
    public UserControlA()
    {
        IntializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControlA_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Authorize();
    }
}
```

I only want to know why the `Loaded` event is fired without any reason?

Comment: The Loaded event is not fired without a reason. It is fired when the element is loaded, as you might guess from its name.

Comment: @Clemens does that mean every time a usercontrol is initialized, Loaded event is fired, l the reason I ask is as I mentioned there are a few (5) usercontrols, so each Usercontrol is added to the grid one by one, only but only one usercontrols's Visibility is set to visible while the rest are Collapsed, so why does all Loaded event need to be fired at once

Comment: See [Object Lifetime Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: The methods are not the events. They are the event handlers aka callbacks that get invoked when the event that they are registered with gets raised. `UserControlA_Loaded` is the event handler for the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event. Maybe the `Initialized` event is more suitable for you? Since you have tagged your question with "mvvm", you should follow this pattern and handle authorization in the view model and then set a e.g. `IsAuthorized` property (read-only) on the data model accordingly. This should not be part of the control.